# Function call out of constructor

Tags: angular, typescript

is there another way to call a function from a service class without calling it in the constructor?
i did try to call the function out of the constructor but it wont give me the result of ShowDanger from **Toast.service.ts**

Example.

**toast.service.ts**

```
export class ToastService {
  toasts: any[];

  show(textOrTpl: string | TemplateRef<any>, options: any = {}) {
    if (!this.toasts) {
      this.toasts = [];
    }
    this.toasts.push({ textOrTpl, ...options });
  }
  showDanger(dangerTpl: string | TemplateRef<any>) {
    this.show(dangerTpl, { classname: 'bg-danger text-light', delay: 5000 });
  }
```

**Parent.service.ts**

```
constructor(
private toastService = ToastService
)

get<T>(queryParams?, customEndpoint?: string): Observable<T> {
        let httpUrl = this.httpUrl;

        this.http.get<T>(
            `${httpUrl}`,
            { observe: 'response' }
        )
            .subscribe(resp => {
            },
                err => {
                    if (err.status === 400) {
                        this.toastsService.showDanger('Input Error');

                    } else if (err.status === 500) {
                        this.toastsService.showDanger('Communication Error');

                    } else {
                        this.toastsService.showDanger('Network Issues');
                    }
                }
            );
         }
```

**Child.service.ts**

```
export class ChildService extends ParentService {

 constructor(toastsService: ToastService) {
    super(toastsService);
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have `private toastService = ToastService`? Shouldn't it be `private toastService: ToastService`? Normally, ChildService shouldn't need to call super on its parent to initiate the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Change the parent.service.ts's constructor to

```
constructor(private toastService: ToastService)
```